# how to refresh part of a component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, datagrid, javascript-objects

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import CloudTables from '@cloudtables/react';
import { useState } from 'react';


function DataGridTable  ({ input1Value, input2Value }) 
{
  
    return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
     <section  >
          <div>
      <p>Received values:</p>
      <p>Input 1: {input1Value}</p>
      <p>Input 2: {input2Value}</p>
      <button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
         handleinput();
         refresh();
        }}>click!</button>
    </div>
      <CloudTables
      src={input1Value}
      apiKey={input2Value} ></CloudTables>
      </section>

    </div>
  );
}
export default DataGridTable
```

input1Value andr input2Value comes from another component and cloudtables doesnt refresh itself when they changed the other component is;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TokenText({ onButtonClick }) {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    onButtonClick(input1, input2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
        <section  >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter text for input 1"
        value={input1}
        onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter text for input 2"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div className="d-grid gap-2">
      <button  variant="primary" onClick={handleButtonClick}>Send to Another Component</button>
      </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TokenText;
```

when they arrive i want the refresh the dataGridTable. how do i do it?
refreshing whole page didnt work tho whish is: const refresh = () => window.location.reload(true)

Comment: `<CloudTables key={input1Value}
      src={input1Value}
      apiKey={input2Value} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@cloudtables/react source code](https://bitbucket.org/sprymedia/cloudtables-react/src/fea953d2050d0979416d571b19ba1effecd2dc13/src/lib/components/cloudtables.js#lines-4:22), it creates an instance on mount using `src` and `apiKey`, then never update it again.

You can

1. Only initiate the `CloudTables` when `src` and `apiKey` are confirmed
2. Or you can add `key` attribute to `CloudTables` so it will remount everytime those values are changed

   <CloudTables key={input1Value + input2Value} src={input1Value} apiKey={input2Value} />